# Who to follow up on; the local staffing agency, the recruitment director, or the recruiter who contacted me?

Tags: professionalism, communication, job-offer

I was contacted (lets call him Contact A) a month ago for a job outside my country. I sent my CV and took the exam and passed.

A week later, I was scheduled for an interview by Contact A with their recruitment director (let's call him Contact B) to be facilitated by a local staffing agency in charge of processing my VISA. I flew over and nailed the interview, with the director (Contact B) telling me I ranked 6 out of 80 in the exams despite me being very young and walking me outside the room, congratulating me, and declaring to his colleague and the local agency contact (Contact C) to "Get this man *(me)* on a plane to *(prospect country)*, but first get him back to *(where I'm from)*" (jokingly, we had a very fun interview)

Contact C then told me to wait for a follow up next week (the interview happened last Oct. 16 Friday)

The week is ending (it's now Oct 23 here) and I've been very anxious. Should I contact Contact C? What about Contact A?

I do not have an immediate contact with Contact B, but his LinkedIn profile is in their website; should I send him a message there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Talk to Contact C, as they were your point of contact for the follow up.  If you get no response, talk to Contact A.

If nothing then, let it go.  Do not contact Contact B if you haven't been given their contact details and he already delegated responsibility to Contact C.

Comment: Thank you Jane. I apologize for asking this in a comment, but do you think it's ethical to add Contact B in LinkedIn?

Comment: You can _invite_ Contact B, but they may not respond to your invitation.